# $wpdb->get_results() does not fetch results with unicode 'WHERE' clause

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql, wpdb

I've just a simple query to fetch a students records by his name, written in Bengali.

```
$student_rcrd = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM student WHERE name='আবুল কালাম আজাদ'");
```

Although my database have a record for 'আবুল কালাম আজাদ', the query returns zero row! But instead of this query, it works absolutely fine-

```
$student_rcrd = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM student WHERE name='Abul Kalam Azad'");
```

- The name field in the database is 'utf8_unicode_ci'

Comment: Did you check the SQL directly, like from PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Also, if you are using the unicode text directly in the file (not from user input), then make sure the `php` file itself is saved as unicode `UTF8` (without BOM) from your editor.

Comment: I have checked the SQL from phpMyAdmin and it returns the row. the unicode text is actually inserted by the user. For Simplification I mentioned the query directly.

Comment: Check what charset is defined in wp config file. try setting this define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'); or define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

Comment: tried both, still not working! :(

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be a collation issue. Try using: `add_filter( 'pre_get_table_charset', '__return_false' );` before the query and see if it works. If it does, then it's a collation issue (don't actually use it on production, this is just for test).

Comment: thanks @Fayaz, it worked finally. but what about 'production' you mentioned, i actually didn't get it.

Comment: I meant this is not actually a solution (even though it works). So you shouldn't use it on live sites (i.e. production). By this test we can rule out some other possible issues and say for sure that it's a database collation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your data are possibly corrupt from trying to store multibyte characters that your DB could not correctly represent. MySQL's `utf8` collation [isn't actually UTF-8](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434). You will have to convert your tables' character sets to `utf8mb4` (real UTF-8), and then set the `DB_CHARSET` constant to match.